# Running Jest tests cause 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag)' of undefined'

Tags: node.js, jestjs, travis-ci

I am using travis-ci for deployment of my open source projects. Without changes in my code, since yesterday all my builds fail to run unit tests with the next error:

```
~/w/some-package ❯❯❯ yarn test
yarn run v1.13.0
$ jest
 FAIL  test/unit/lib/sometest.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag)' of object '#<process>'

      at _default (node_modules/jest-util/build/createProcessObject.js:85:34)
```

My build configuration uses the latest node and just runs the tests

```
language: node_js
node_js:
 - node
script:
 - yarn test
```

Was there any change of dependencies of travis-ci machines? is there any compatibility in between versions of node and jest?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to be an incompatibility in between node `11.11.0` that is the latest stable release and jest versions before `24.3.0`.

There are currently 2 solutions:

- Upgrade Jest (this will use a version of jest that is compatible with node 11.11)

```
yarn upgrade jest --latest
```

- Pin version of node in .travis.yml (this will make sure that travis uses a version of node that is compatible with older jest versions)

```
language: node_js
node_js:
 - "10.15.3"
script:
 - yarn test
```

Comment: if you are using npm and not yarn you can use `npm update jest` command

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to `jest 24.3.1` solves the issue as it was fixed in the version 24.3.0.

The `pre-24.3.x`version are incompatible with `node 11.11.0`.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/8069#issuecomment-470930698. So, just update the jest package version, remove the node_modules and the package-lock.json, then reinstall all dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that you added a new Service in the Constructor but you forgot to add it in the spec file.

I would recommend to create a Mockup with the methods you need from that service:

```
const utilServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('utilService', ['isNewFeatureEnabled']);
```

then you add it as a provider:

```
{ provide: UtilService, useValue: utilServiceMock},
```

and finally inject it:

```
utilServiceSpy = TestBed.inject(UtilService);
```

(the last 2 steps you can put them into **beforeEach** trigger)